# What would be the most appropriate way to transform xml data to sql server database

Tags: c#, sql-server, xml, .net-4.0

I am looking for some probable choices to efficiently populate a relational SQL Server database from xml files. So basically I visualize a three step process to accomplish it;

1. Read XML from a public url
2. populate sql db which is similar to xml schema
3. populate the target relational sql db.

I am not sure if mapping the xml directly to the target db is achieveable easily ie. skipping step 2, but my inclination is that it would make the process a little bit complicated.

The xml reading part from a public url would be something like www.abc.com/xmlfeed.xml which would require a nightly routine to make this file available to be processed. Some thing like windows task schedular..or any better way?

I have only two days to make this work, so I would prefer anything that is quick to implement with less coding effort. However I do need this method to be maintainable in the future, as I would be receiving the new xml data every day with the same old schema. In case the schema changes a little bit, I would like the process of tweaking the routine to be hassle free.

I thought that migration of legacy data to SQL Server would be a few minutes task due to the frequency of such requirement, but to my surprise there are very little discussion/comparisions on the internet for different xml migration techniques.I am really confused to decide on the route that I should take, a pure SQL Server solution like SSIS or something like xml parsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I read your post through, my very first idea was SSIS, and at the end you wrote it yourself. Especially if you are familiar with it, I recommend it. You can implement such a solution in two days.

After you implemented the ETL process you can create an SQL Server Agent job which will schedule your SSIS package to run at the time you want it to run. It supports running packages from SQL Server or File System.

#### EDIT

According to your example. It's fully possibe to implement such a solution in SSIS. I give some screenshot about a sample project which process your XML sturcture.

1. First image shows that the SSIS package consists of 3 control flow steps. Each of them is a Data Flow Task. First it process the manufacturers then the models then cars.

   [image: Sample SSIS package]
2. I implemented only the manufacturers part. This is shown in image #2 and #3. (They overlap a little bit.) In #2 I read the XML content (XML Source task), aggregate it (Aggregation task) by manufacturer. Then I sort them also by manufacturer name (Sort task). On the other side I read the manufacturers existing in SQL database (through OLE DB Source task), then this will be also sorted.

   [image: Process manufacturers part 1]
3. After that these two sources are merged (Merge join task) by a join operation (similar as in SQL). In this case this is a FULL OUTER JOIN so you can figure out which manufacturer is new and which one should be deleted. I split the records into two parts according the previous two conditions (new, deleted).

   [image: Process manufacturers part 2]
4. Finally I add the new manufacturers through an OLE DB Destination task, and delete the missing manufacturers with the help of an OLE DB Command task. In the latter case I assume there's a stored procedure (called DeleteManufacturer(@ManufacturerName)) in SQL which will delete the manufacturer and all attached models and cars. (Cascade Delete)

The other two data flow tasks should be implemented in the same way. If you should uptade the matching records, the Conditional Split task must have three conditions and a new tree bunch attached to this third condition. Here a new OLE DB Command can be used with an UPDATE statement.

As I wrote previously if you are ready with the package, an SQL Server Agent job should be created, which will run your package at night (or at the time you wish).

Comment: Since i am new to SSIS, I might have to consider the learning curve. Is there a way to map an xml directly to the target relational db? I mean skipping the step 2 to populate an intermediate db. Would i have to write any queries for it? If you can point me to some resource which explains this whole process, it would be great.

Comment: Can you provide information about the differences in XML and target database schema? (Not all but a little extract about why you think you need an intermadiate DB.) There are tools in SSIS to transform your XML as you like. I can help you if you give some more infos.

Comment: Say the feed is like
<auctionlist>
    <car >
     number="2"
     <model>
      <name>camry</name>
      <manufacturer>toyota</manufacturer>
     <\model>
    <\car>
    <car >
     number="3"
     <model>
      <name>accord</name>
      <manufacturer>honda</manufacturer>
     <\model>
    <\car>
    <car >
     number="4"
     <model>
      <name>civic</name>
      <manufacturer>honda</manufacturer>
     <\model>
    <\car>
<\auctionlist>

Comment: Say the target db has tables Manufacturers, Models, Cars.
I would need to fill the Manufacturers table first, so to refer it as foriegn key in models and finally the cars which will have a reference to the model. Plus there could be other things like filling up the images table for each of the car with car id and so on. How easy it would be as i would be getting the feed every day to update the db with new cars, delete cars which are not in the xml feed or update them if they already exist.

Comment: Great detailed explanation!.Though just because of my fear of this little learning curve, i didnt took the SSIS route. But this surely looks like a very clean and easy way to migrate xml data to sql server. I did manage however to complete the migration in 2 days without the headache of xml parsing. I used .net Dataset to read the xml and dump the data to a identical db structure. In the 2nd step , i implemented my mapping bussiness logic to the target relational db using plain sql queries. Though, i would not recommend it, specially after things like SSIS, but it did the trick.